# Mapping unstructured schema elements into a structured

Tags: xslt, mapping

I just want to convert from this the hotel_info structure to the AvailableHotels structure:  The hotel_info XML comes from a legacy SOAP web service and my goal is to the structure AvailableHotels ; The elements required from the hotel_info occur in various places

```
       <hotel_info>
        <AvailableHotels>
                    <hotel_1>
                       <hotelName_1>safd1</hotelName_1>
                       <booked_by>Taylor Volkes</booked_by>
                       <booking_id>sdf</booking_id>
                    </hotel_1>
                    <hotel_2>
                       <hotelName_1>safd2</hotelName_1>
                       <booked_by>Sam Volkes</booked_by>
                       <booking_id>sdf</booking_id>
                    </hotel_2>
        </AvailableHotels>
         <hotel_details>
                        <detail>  
                        <hotelReference>hotel_1</hotelReference>
                        <reservation_complete>Yes</reservation_complete>
                        <hotelAddress1>sd</hotelAddress1>
                        <hotelAddress2>sd</hotelAddress2>
                        <hotelCity>sd</hotelCity>
                        <hotelState>sd</hotelCity>
                        <hotelState>AK</hotelState>
                        <suite_required>Yes</suite_required>
                        <email_provided>sdfeiwocmed</email_provided>
                        <hotelState__b_>HI</hotelState__b_>
                        </detail>
                        <detail>  
                        <hotelReference>hotel_2</hotelReference>
                        <reservation_complete>Yes</reservation_complete>
                        <hotelAddress1>sd</hotelAddress1>
                        <hotelAddress2>sd</hotelAddress2>
                        <hotelCity>sd</hotelCity>
                        <hotelState>sd</hotelCity>
                        <hotelState>AK</hotelState>
                        <suite_required>Yes</suite_required>
                        <email_provided>sdfeiwocmed</email_provided>
                        <hotelState__b_>HI</hotelState__b_>
                        </detail>
        </hotel_details>
   <hotel_info>
```

To this:

```
  <AvailableHotels>
    <hotel>
        <HotelName>hotel_1</HotelName>
        <HotelAddressLine1Text></HotelAddressLine1Text>
        <HotelAddressLine2Text></HotelAddressLine2Text>
        <HotelCityName></HotelCityName>
        <HotelStateCode></HotelStateCode>
        <HotelZip5Code></HotelZip5Code>
        <HotelZip4Code></HotelZip4Code>
        <reservation_status>booked</reservation_status>
    </hotel>
   <hotel>
        <HotelName>hotel_2</HotelName>
        <HotelAddressLine1Text></HotelAddressLine1Text>
        <HotelAddressLine2Text></HotelAddressLine2Text>
        <HotelCityName></HotelCityName>
        <HotelStateCode></HotelStateCode>
        <HotelZip5Code></HotelZip5Code>
        <reservation_status>booked</reservation_status>
        <HotelZip4Code></HotelZip4Code>
    </hotel>            
  </AvailableHotels>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please provide a better example of the input - see: [mcve]

Comment: What input? It's a web service call.  I provided examples of the output i.e AvailabieLodgingAddress1 and AvailableLodgingNames elements which exist as individual elements as well as others in the returned XML from the SOAP service.  These need to be mapped to the AavailableHotels complex element

Comment: What input? The input to the XSL transformation.Your example is not well-formed **and** taken out of context. And context is crucial in XSLT.

Comment: I have made the question more clearer, hope this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step by step:

- Create the output to render the `AvailableHotels -hotel - HotelName` part
- create a variable curHotel with `name()` of the tags inside your `AvailableHotels`
- use the parameter as selection criteria for `apply-templates` something along the lines of `<xsl:apply-templates select="/hotel_info/hotel_details/detail[hotelReference=$curHotel]" />`

(off my head, might contain typos)

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Post your working style sheet as update to your question, so other seekers can benefit

Comment: Unfortunately, I had to repurpose the data as it involves the use of an API I cannot divulge.

Comment: That's lame. You have input and output sample in your question, you can provide the XSLT you used for that sample. Nobody asks for real data here :-)